# Android Facebook development key changes on every phone

Tags: android, facebook

I have facebook login setup in my android app.  When the user clicks login (with the facebook app installed on their phone) the app returns:

"Login Failed: invalid_key: Android Key mismatch. Your key"

This happens on every phone but my development phone.  I generated the key through the facebook developer site with this command: keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

I assume the problem is the registered key in facebook is for debug when it needs to be for distribution.  If this the case how do i create the distribution key that will be valid for all apps downloaded from the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround for apps using FB SDK. You can create debug keystore with your release key (by exporing and importing via JDK keytool or GUI tool such as [KeyStore Explorer for Windows](http://www.lazgosoftware.com/kse/index.html) or it's analog for any other OS).

Your new keystore and key should have the following credentials (by android dev guide):

- Keystore password: "android"
- Key alias: "androiddebugkey"
- Key password: "android"

After it provide path to new keystore in eclipse or ant.properties and calculate a hash for your new debug key that **will be equal** to a hash of your old release key (for example using [android-fb-keytool](http://code.google.com/p/android-fb-keytool/), that doesn't require JDK or OpenSSL).

Comment: Thank you so much, I ran into this problem too, your suggestion works perfectly. Created a new debug.keystore based on my release key, with the good alias and password and everything is working.

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is happening for your app when it's installed on customer's phones from the Android Market (Google Play)?  If so, then you doubtless used a different keystore file and alias to sign the app for distribution.  In which case, execute the same series of commands, just substitute the distribution keystore file name for `~/.android/debug.keystore` and alias for `androiddebugkey`, then add the resulting signature to your Facebook app.

Comment: yes it android market/play apps.  Are you saying I substitute debug.keystore for the key I use to sign my apps for the android market?  Also can the alias stay androiddebugkey if I don't know my alias?

Comment: You'll need to know the name of the file containing the keystore you used to sign the Market version of your app as well as the name of the alias you used to sign your apps. So the command would look something like: `keytool -exportcert -alias android-release -keystore app-release.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`  Of course, you would replace "android-release" with the name of the alias you used to sign the Market version of the app and replace "app-release.keystore" with the name/path of the appropriate (not debug) keystore.